# How to unit test winform keypress and button events

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, unit-testing

```
private void Phonenumber_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    char ch = e.KeyChar;
    if (!char.IsDigit(ch) && (ch != 8))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}

private void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //sql commands
    messagebox.show("data added successfully");
}
```

Comment: Hey mate, I wouldn't test that one. Google about "What code should I unit test".

Comment: It's better to find some best practices or samples not just asking about others's idea

Comment: Basically, this can be tested not relative to buttons. I mean, that you can have some method, for example ProcessUserInput(char someChar) and test it

Comment: Because you want to test code where UI framework involved(Winforms), you need to start application, open the form, input text into textbox and press a button, then assert that message box with expected message have been displayed. You can check TestStack.White framework which provides API for doing all steps mentioned above.

Comment: Other way is to do it manually. Based on the requirements, it can be quicker ;)

Answer (score 1):

Its better to add a method which is testable and then calling that method inside evant as below (code for sample only and not tested in ide)

```
private void Phonenumber_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
     e.Handled= IsWrongkeypress(e.KeyChar)
}

public Boolean  IsWrongkeypress(char ch)
        {
            Boolean ishandled =false ;

            if (!char.IsDigit(ch) && (ch != 8))
            {
                ishandled = true;
            }

            return ishandled;
        }
```

Comment: it is effecting the other code..can you please write..main methos and test case code seperately

Comment: what effect canyou ellaborate.so that i can help

Comment: it not effecting anything..I have solved that... But Can you write code for unit testing Phonenumber keypress event ..The above code which you have writtern is confusing..write two codes which I need to be change in main method and code for unit testing..